# $X,Y\geq 0$ are R.V.s s.t., $\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{-tY}]$ for all $t>0$. Show X=Y in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Having issues getting started with this one.

Let $X,Y\geq 0$ be random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{-tY}]$ for all $t>0$. Show X=Y in distribution.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you know about MGF?

Comment: Yes, but the MGF doesn't uniquely determine the distributions, right? I know the answer probably does have to do with it, but I cant make the connection. @Epsilon

Comment: If the MGF exists then it determines the distribution uniquely. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties

Comment: Still, I'm not sure if we can say that it necessarily exists in this case, since we only are given that it holds for $t>0$. @Epsilon

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1.** We claim the following:

> **Claim.** Let $\varphi \in C([0, 1])$ be such that $\varphi = 0$ near $x = 0$. Then
>   $$\Bbb{E}[\varphi(e^{-tX})] = \Bbb{E}[\varphi(e^{-tY})]. \tag{1} $$

This claim indeed implies that $X \stackrel{d}{=} Y$. To see this, for any sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ define $\varphi_{\epsilon}$ as a continuous function on $[0, 1]$ whose graph is obtained by joining $(0, 0)$, $(e^{-1}-\epsilon, 0)$, $(e^{-1}, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$ as below:

$\hspace{9em}$[image: Approximation of step function]

Then for any $t > 0$, $\text{(1)}$ gives

$$ \Bbb{E}[\varphi_{\epsilon}(e^{-X/t})] = \Bbb{E}[\varphi_{\epsilon}(e^{-Y/t})]. $$

Now take $\epsilon \downarrow 0$. Then $\varphi_{\epsilon}(x) \downarrow \mathbf{1}_{[e^{-1}, 1]}(x)$ and by the dominated convergence theorem we have

$$ \Bbb{P}(X \leq t)
= \Bbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{[e^{-1}, 1]}(e^{-X/t})]
= \Bbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{[e^{-1}, 1]}(e^{-Y/t})]
= \Bbb{P}(Y \leq t). $$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative, this proves that $X$ and $Y$ have the same CDF and hence the same distribution.

**Step 2.** So it remains to prove the claim. Let $\varphi$ be as in the assertion of the claim. Then $x^{-1}\varphi$ is also continuous, so by Stone-Weierstrass theorem there exists a sequence of polynomial $p_n(x)$ that converges uniformly to $x^{-1}\varphi(x)$ on $[0, 1]$. Then $xp_n(x)$ is a polynomial *without constant term* that converges uniformly to $\varphi(x)$ on $[0, 1]$. Consequently,

$$ \Bbb{E}[\varphi(e^{-tX})]
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \Bbb{E}[e^{-tX}p_n(e^{-tX})]
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \Bbb{E}[e^{-tY}p_n(e^{-tY})]
= \Bbb{E}[\varphi(e^{-tY})] $$

and the claim follows.

Comment: Nice proof. At the end, $X$ in the exponent should be $Y$.

Comment: @MathewJames D'oh, it was indeed a silly typo :( I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
\{z\in \Bbb {C} \mid Re (z) <0\}\to \Bbb {C}, z \mapsto \Bbb {E}(e^{z X}).
$$
and the analogoulsy defined function for $Y $.

Show that these are holomorphic. By the identity theorem and your assumption, they coincide. By continuity, we also get coincidence for $Re (z)=0$.

Thus, the Fourier transforms of $X,Y $ coincide and so does there distribution.